# .htaccess rewrite rule not working for different pages

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I had the page name as the-book.html, but now i changed the page name to about-the-book. I have used the rewrite rule as

```
`Redirect 301 /the-book.html http://www.xxx.com/about-the-book.html`
```

but it is not working.

my full .htaccess code is here

```
RewriteRule ^/the-book.html$ http://www.xxx.com/about-the-book.html [R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase /` need to come before **any** `RewriteRule`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^the-book.html$ http://www.example.com/about-the-book.html [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `Redirect` directive, but

```
RewriteRule ^the-book.html$ http://www.xxx.com/about-the-book.html [R=301]
```

should work nicely.

Edit:
Removed the leading `/` in the match part.